# Struggling to get started with Entity Framework from an existing SQL database

Tags: sql, azure, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I just created a database in Azure and I was trying to get it started with EF by connecting to this existing database.

I am completely new to .NET and EF, so most of the examples I saw are similar but different enough to get me lost.

The database does not have any tables.

What would be the easiest way to setup a EF configuration and a simple model to connect and create/map my model to the database?

Preferable something that I can do with the CLI and VS Code.

Thank you all.

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-database-first - scaffold is your friend

Comment: Oh, wait.. Just noticed: *The DB does not have any tables* - well it's not really a database then! Go create some tables, relationships etc.. Then scaffold. Or use [code first](https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-code-first)

Comment: I tried that from the code samples but they have files I don't have or the version of visual studio just don't make sense to me.

I tried the tuts from the docs and youtube. I am probably doing something wrong cause everytime they either editing a file I don't have in my src or a different approach than the one I am trying.

Comment: There are two ways in EntityFramework
1. Scaffold - where you create tables in DB and create models based on the tables you have created.
2. Code First - where you created models and create tables in DB based on the models you have created.

both has pros and cons. First decide how you want to do it, and then search for tutorials for that way!

Comment: Ok, the example from the tuts with EF Core. works:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app

Comment: but if I try to add a sql conenction on the model config step I get: Login failed for user 'dbuser' I already have firewall configured there as well. I could connect from vsstudio but this one from EF Core I can't really run it.

Comment: That, alas, is nothing to do with your question here. That's not being able to log in to SQL server, and given that you can do it from vs it means you do know/can get a working Connection string so there shouldn't be any problem in using the same string in your setup for ef ([UseSqlServer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-5.0) method )

Comment: Right, I just figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So, I was using the wrong password for the connection... replacing the "UseSqlite" to "UseSqlServer" plus the correct connection string worked.

then running "dotnet ef database update" generated the tables :D

Thank you all who commented.